# Deleting dynamic objects with a destructor? C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-management

I have a few objects throughout the program that are facing a similar issue.  One example:

I have an Image class:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    Image(const Image& copy);
    ~Image();

    void loadimage(string filename);
    void saveimage(string filename);
    Image superimpose(const Image& ontop, Color mask);

    int getwidth();
    int getheight();
    Image operator=(const Image&);

protected:    
    Color** pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
    ImageLoader* loader;
};
```

It has a copy constructor:

```
Image::Image(const Image& copy)
{
    width = copy.width;
    height = copy.height;
    loader = copy.loader;

    pixels = new Color*[height];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] = new Color[width];
    }

    for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            pixels[h][w] = copy.pixels[h][w];
        }
    }
}
```

Color is a struct:

```
struct Color
{
    unsigned int r;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int b;
};
```

My concern is that I create a dynamic two-dimensional array of Color structs, but I'm not sure when and where to delete it.  I implemented the following in my Image destructor, but I'm not 100% certain that it's doing the job and I'm not sure how to check if it does:

```
Image::~Image()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        delete[] pixels[i];
    }

    delete[] pixels;
    pixels = NULL;
}
```

Am I implementing the memory deallocation correctly?

Comment: The most correct way would be to not implement it at all and use something that will do manage the memory for you. Also, setting something that's about to be destroyed to `NULL` is pretty pointless.

Comment: @chris So.... what would I use?  You didn't mention.

Comment: I generally prefer a `Matrix` class that encapsulates a 1D `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK.

Two points, you can use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and get rid of self deleting the memory.

Second is, I prefer use `nullptr` or `0` instead of `NULL` *(although it's standard)*. Moreover, since the container object is destroying, you don't need to set its member to null.

And the best is using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Color>> pixels;

...

Image::Image(const Image& copy)
{
    width = copy.width;
    height = copy.height;
    loader = copy.loader;

    pixels.resize(height);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        pixels[i].resize(width);
    }

    for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            pixels[h][w] = copy.pixels[h][w];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `unique_ptr`, which is more efficient than `vector` here. But `shared_ptr` doesn't support arrays.

Comment: How would you implement unique_ptr in this scenario?  I've read up on them, but I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I implementing the memory deallocation correctly?

Yes. It is correct. However, you'd better replace the 2D dynamic array with `vector of vectors`, which manages memory by itself, safer and less error prone.

Comment: Thank you, I might have to do that if I can't figure out the unqiue_ptr that was suggested by M M.

Comment: @Noobacode You are welcome. You may find a lot of posts about unique_ptr on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I see a lack of RAII here and problems with potential exceptions thrown like bad_alloc which will leave your object in an undefined state. I would allocate the memomry in an object that manages memory for you and so when the object is out of scope it will destroy itself. Said object should also provide a copy construtor that deep copies memory and allows you to access the raw data through a pointer to the first byte. std::vector has all these attributes.

Comment: Never heard of RAII before you mentioned it, thank you.  It's a good read.